# Webpack 4: content hash filename?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Is there a way to put the hash of the chunk content into the filename of each file, rather than the hash of the entire chunk?

I'm using this right now:

```
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        chunkFilename: 'chunk.[chunkhash].js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[hash].css',
            chunkFilename: 'chunk.[chunkhash].css',
        }),
    ],
```

But if I modify the JS file, the `[chunkhash]` of the CSS file changes too, and vice-versa. There's no reason to invalidate the cache of a file that hasn't changed.

Comment: This would be a great GitHub issue as I don't believe we have `contenthash` support yet for this plugin. GitHub.com/webpack-contribs/mini-css-extract-plugin

Comment: @SeanLarkin Would it not be better to tackle this from the core? Adding `[contenthash]` to `mini-css-extract-plugin` would solve the problem if the CSS filenames changing when I edit the JS, but not vice-versa, correct? And the problem will keep coming up every time new file types are supported, no?

Comment: That's a good point but I recall there was some limitation that I can't speak to at the very moment. You could also submit to webpack/webpack and start from there. Then we can dive into the viability of the feature across all asset types, etc.

Comment: @SeanLarkin Actually there's already a PR for adding it to minicss: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/pull/30

Comment: The wording on this issue is a little funny, but I think it's the same problem: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/672

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of both `webpack` (at least `^4.5.0`) and the `mini-css-extract-plugin` (at least `^0.9.0`) support the `[contenthash]` placeholder in `output.filename` and `filename` respectively.